# Joomla migration issue

Tags: joomla

I have transferred my website to a new server after updating the files and database I am getting this issue

Table 'jimcorbe_jimcorbe.xpivg_session' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `xpivg_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('18f0b96cfc5e1cb723b8405137ff36a6', 0, '1427709725')

I am very new to joomla so could not understand what it means. Can anyone provide me with the solution to get back my website live.

Answer (score 0):

During the migration, it's possible that database table prefixes have changed.

Open PhpMyAdmin and look for the session table. If it doesn't exist, run the following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xpivg_session` (
  `session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guest` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `time` varchar(14) DEFAULT '',
  `data` mediumtext,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  `usertype` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I ran up the above querry but now its showing blank page !

Comment: Please set error reporting in your Joomla Global Configuration to `development` which will show you any errors

Comment: I appreciate you efforts you are taking in solving my Issue. As I am very new to joomla so can you please help me out how can I set error reporting in your Joomla Global Configuration ?

Comment: http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-basics/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-joomla-25